# Laravel $request->all() is empty But $_POST returns the actual posted data in the form correctly

Tags: post, request, laravel-5.4

I am facing an issue with Laravel request which seems pretty weird to me.
On `POST` when I check `$request->all()` it returns an empty array. But `$_POST` returns the actual posted data in the form correctly.

I am injecting the Request in the method as well.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function test(Request $request) {
       $postedData = $request->all();
       return response()->json($postedData);
}
```

I am also passing the csrf token in the form.
I have also tried the questions that are already here on Stack Overflow.

My Laravel version is 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix this issue.
It was because in the project there was a middleware in which

below line was causing the issue. 
I removed this header and it was all fine.

```
$request->headers->set('Content-Type','application/json')
```